# Display content of two separate divs upon tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am using MaterializeCSS tabs to display content on my website. I would like each tab to initiate content of two div's at once but am having troubles making this work.

I tried using data-target on each of the tabs but this didn't work. Now I am including two href's in each tab but this doesn't work either. I would appreciate if someone can help with this.

```
<div class="menu-section">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#overview,#test1">Overview</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#howto,#test2">How to use</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#integration,#test3">Integration</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#compatibility,#test4">Compatibility</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#terms,#test5">Terms of Service</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="overview" class="col s12">test 1</div>
    <div id="howto" class="col s12">test 2</div>
    <div id="integration" class="col s12">test 3</div>
    <div id="compatibility" class="col s12">test 4</div>
    <div id="terms" class="col s12">test 5</div>
  </div>

  <div id="test1" class="col s12">test 1</div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12">test 2</div>
  <div id="test3" class="col s12">test 3</div>
  <div id="test4" class="col s12">test 4</div>
  <div id="test5" class="col s12">test 5</div>
```

And my jquery initialization:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  });
```

Comment: You cannot give routing for two ids in the same href like ( href="#overview,#test1").  That means href considers that whole thing as a single id.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs').tabs();
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
 <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>
<title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
<body>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#howto">How to use</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#integration">Integration</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#compatibility">Compatibility</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#terms">Terms of Service</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="overview" class="col s12">test 1</div>
    <div id="howto" class="col s12">test 2</div>
    <div id="integration" class="col s12">test 3</div>
    <div id="compatibility" class="col s12">test 4</div>
    <div id="terms" class="col s12">test 5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```